# How to solve ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16 error in python

Tags: python

I tries to convert a hexadecimal to a decimal number in python. I tried the following:

```
if isinstance(expr, pyvex.IRExpr.Load):
      loadaddr = expr.addr
       s = int (loadaddr, 16)
       print s
```

But I encountered error: 
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base``

Then I tried the following:

```
i = int('"{}"'.format(loadaddr), 16) 
print i
```

Now I encountered the following error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '"0x00000000004017c0"'
.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You're adding unnecessary quotes. Try `int('{}'.format(loadaddr), 16)`, which (depending on how `pyvex.IRExpr.Load` is defined) probably isn't much different than `int(str(loadaddr), 16)`.